# Why doesn't it report error with wrong parameter type?

Tags: python

```
def nlp_dict(input_doc:dict):
  text = input_doc['text']
```

I suppose it will report an error if I call the function with:

```
nlp_dict('A test')
```

The correct form should be:

```
nlp_dict({'text': 'A test'})
```

The error occurs at the 2nd line:

```
text = input_doc['text']
```

Why doesn't error occur immediately when the compiler finds its argument type is a str, not a dict? So what's the value of the argument type?

Comment: Python is a dynamic language, and the compiler does **no static analysis of nominal, annotated types**.  This is *very important to understand*

Answer (score 0):

Type hints are just that; hints to IDEs and not some type enforcement mechanism!

3rd party tools like Pydantic extend this to do runtime type checking

Comment: Is Pydantic widely used, or not commonly used?

Comment: sure, but it's not used exactly how you're trying to, and just enables runtime type checks by extending type hints (this is used, for example, in FastAPI to describe the API to clients and validate requests)

Comment: @marlon there are several third-party static analysis tools, `mypy`, `pyright`, `pytype`. `mypy` is probably the closest to an "official" one, mainly, because Guido is part of the active development.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is it a good practice to use  mypy or similar tools to do static type checking in python?

Comment: @marlon that is entirely up to you. I find it very helpful for any non trivially sized project.